# Submit search text in value attribute in textbox , How to concatenate?

Tags: html, search, textbox

```
<input type="text" value="Orchard" id="tag" name="tag" class="input-text"/>
```

In a html textbox I supply word Orchard and it is getting a list of orchard pics in my site.

I have some words like orchard garden, orchard for sale and so on...

If I supply as Orchard Garden, a + is coming in between them and i can get results from db. (db coding are not done by me, it were already completed by sql people)

So what the soln?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`+` character is an encoded space](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#didx-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded). Your server form handling library *should* take care of that for you.

If it doesn't, then you are either:

- Using a broken form handling library that needs to be fixed or replaced
- Bypassing the decoding functionality of your library (don't do that)
  or
- Not using a form handling library at all (Start. Handling form data is complex enough that it is not worth reinventing the wheel)